# Ethereum Wallet sync problems

Tags: wallets, synchronization

Cheers, please don't laugh to my stupidity. I need some extra space on my SSD and firstly checked what takes the most of the space. Almost at the top were files under Ethereum Chaindata. I stupidly went in and deleted most off them...as I thought they were history, which don't really matter. Well, I can't sync my Wallet anymore. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"...deleted most off them"_. If you've _partly_ deleted the chaindata, then it's likely that you've left the database in an unsane state. The best thing to do would be to delete the remnants and start again from scratch. (Before you do anything else, **make sure you have a backup of your keystore files!**)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks got it right: PLEASE backup your `keystore`.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `chaindata`, and do a sync again, this time with the `--fast` option. It will use less space.

EDIT: And please, make a backup of the `keystore`! As a fellow poster wrote above!